# Clarify notifications when earning a badge multiple times at once

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, notifications

SuperUser just notified me that I earned the **Nice Answer** badge and one other badge and suggested I'd visit my profile.

Curious about what the *other badge* could possibly be, I complied, but only the **Nice Answer** badge were there.

It took me a few minutes to figure out that I had actually earned the **Nice Answer** badge twice.

To prevent others from facepalming like I did, I'm suggesting the following:

1. Show a multiplier i the activity tab when the same badge is earned multiple times in the same instant.

   Like this:

   [image: proposal]

   **and / or**
2. Change the notification to *You have earned the **Nice Answer** badge twice / thrice / N times*.

Comment: ...wow, not many times you get to see an edge case bug like this. This reminds me of when edits used to be collapsed. I would think the activity tab should show it on two separate lines, not collapse them.

Comment: Since it appears on separate lines when entering *badges* (as @Mr.Wizard pointed out), I guess this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear twice in your activity tab: [(badges tab image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6p2.png).

You're right, I see the problem now:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You're right. When entering *badges*, it **does** appear twice. But it doesn't when you are browsing *all*.

Comment: I think that the behavior on "all" on the activity should probably match that of just badges.